# How to load and save a NeuralDataSet Object - Encog Java

Tags: java, encog

How can I save and load a NeuralDataSet Object with Encog?

This is how I created the object:

```
NeuralDataSet trainingSet = new BasicNeuralDataSet(new double[]{1.0}, new double[]{0.2});
```

Comment: I can't try it out right now, but my guess would be [`EncogUtility#saveCSV`](http://heatonresearch-site.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/javadoc/encog-3.3/org/encog/util/simple/EncogUtility.html#saveCSV%28java.io.File,%20org.encog.util.csv.CSVFormat,%20org.encog.ml.data.MLDataSet%29) (with the corresponding `loadCSV` method). Note that the data set is also `Serializable`, so if the data does not need to be human-readable (and, maybe, this is not intended for long-term storage), you could just write/read it through an `ObjectOutputStream`/`ObjectInputStream`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested [here.](http://heatonresearch-site.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/javadoc/encog-3.3/org/encog/neural/data/NeuralDataSet.html)

*This is an alias class for Encog 2.5 compatibility. This class aliases MLDataSet. Newer code should use MLDataSet in place of this class.*

This is how its done in VB

```
//Saving..
    EncogUtility.SaveEGB(trainingFile, myIMLDataSet);

//Loading..
    myIMLDataSet trainingSet = EncogUtility.LoadEGB2Memory(trainingFile);
```

where **trainingFile** is your FileInfo Object and **myIMLDataSet** is you dataset.

Check out the [examples](https://github.com/encog/encog-dotnet-core) for more information on this.